# How to configure the server in angular to get files?

Tags: node.js, angular

I just run the ng serve command and go to the server. But if I drop the file house.jpg into the src folder, then when I access the address http://localhost:4200/house.jpg then I don’t see this file, the main page of the project opens.
I did not find anything about it in the official documentation, I ask the help of professionals

Comment: Images are served from `assets` folder.  Try putting your image there.

Comment: also, validate angular.json assets folder should be mentioned in the array.

Comment: thanks .-.-.-.-.-.-

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the [Angular Structure Guide](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure). As said above, you need to put your images and other files you want to use frontend-side in the [`assets`](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#application-source-files) folder.

> The `assets` folder contains image and other asset files to be copied as-is when you build your application.

Notice you can create any folders you want in `assets` if you want to order your files.